# Cloned Samsung 970 Evo Plus NVMe SSD won't boot Windows

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd, nvme, macrium

I have a Dell Inspiron 7373 13" laptop which is fitted with a 256GB SATA M.2 SSD. The Dell spec for the laptop states that it can use either SATA M.2 SSDs or NVMe M.2 SSDs. So I ordered a Samsung 970 Evo Plus NVMe M.2 500GB SSD.

I used [Macrium Reflect 7](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree) to first create a Rescue USB then created an image of my existing 256GB SATA drive. Just to clarify, I made a complete image of all the drive partitions.

I removed the 256GB SATA SSD from the laptop and installed the new 500GB NVMe SSD. I rebooted the laptop using the rescue USB and copied the image onto the new NVMe SSD. This all went perfectly.

Finally I shut down the laptop, removed the rescue USB and restarted the laptop but it would not boot into Windows. I tried a boot repair using Macrium and it reported that all was good but the laptop will still not boot from the new drive. I also tried a Windows boot repair but this also failed to solve the problem.

In the BIOS the new drive is visible and I have checked all the BIOS setting and I cannot see anything that will prevent it booting.

The only thing I can think of is that the boot partition that I cloned from my old SSD does not have the NVMe SSD drivers because previously it was a SATA SSD with the SATA drivers.

I have checked Samsung's website and they have an exe file download for installing the NVMe drivers. So I put back my old SATA SSD into my laptop and booted into windows. I checked the device manager for installed drivers and sure enough there was no NVMe driver installed under disk controllers, only SATA driver. So I tried to install the Samsung NVMe driver before taking another image but it will not install the drivers unless a Samsung NVMe SSD is present.

I am now struck, I cannot install the NVMe driver unless the drive is installed but if I install the drive it will not let me boot into windows to install the driver! One thought was to purchase a NVMe external enclosure so I can connect the NVMe SSD via the USB3.1 port, this may then enable me to install the NVMe drivers before I cone the SATA SSD.

Has anyone had the same problem and solved it or can anyone suggest a work around for this problem? I am starting to lose the will to live!!!!

Thanks.

Steve

Comment: Sounds silly but are you sure that your partition is set active?  Have you tried booting with a Windows 10 installation usb and poking around with diskpart to see what windows can see without drivers.  I seriously doubt that you need a driver to boot the new drive.. it is more likely having to do with active partition or master boot record.

Comment: I assume you made a complete image of the first SSD and restored all partitions on the new SSD?  Instead of submitting a comment be sure you clarify this point within the question body.

Comment: Thanks for your responses, yes the drive partition is set to active, I have tried booting with the rescue usb but to be honest I am not that confident to start poking around with diskpart. AS you say, it may be the master boot record that is the problem not a missing driver.

Answer (score 2):

I was upgrading my laptop from an M.2 sata to a larger M.2 nvme drive. I used an external M.2 USB enclosure and Acronis to make a clone of the original drive.  I installed the clone into the laptop but it wouldn't boot (inaccessible boot device). What worked for me was simply booting into safe mode once.  Apparently this enabled the NVME driver to run at boot time from then on.
To do this - When the boot fails and goes to the recover screen select:
Troubleshoot->AdvancedOptions->AdvancedStartupOptions->StartupSettings, then select Restart.  When the computer restarts enter the number (4) for EnableSafeMode. Let safe mode come up, login and restart the computer.

Comment: Safemode with Networking refactors your storage driver. If you've switched from RAID to AHCI or SATA to NVMe, etc. Thx for this reminder. I was stuck until I saw this.

Answer (score 1):

An NVMe drive needs to boot in UEFI mode, and has to be in GPT particioning style.
In order to check these both things, do the following:

1. Boot up with your old SSD.
2. Now, we're going to check the UEFI boot. Be aware thet your BIOS has to support UEFI booting, otherwise this would not work.
3. Press the Windows key + R. Type `msinfo32` and press Enter.
4. Check that next to BIOS mode UEFI is listed. Remember that.
5. Press the Windows key + R, and write `diskmgmt.msc` Press Enter.
6. On the left pane, look for your SSD. If you're unsure which is it, right-click and click propierties on every disk, until you find the one whose name is the one of your old SSD.
7. On the propierties window, go to the volumes tab, and, check that next to partition style, is listed "GUID Particion Table (GPT)"
8. Remember if it says that or "Master Boot Record (MBR)".
9. Install your new NVMe disk, with the already cloned image.
10. Create a [Windows Installation USB](https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/software-download/windows10) **Important:** Create a USB, **not a DVD drive**
11. Boot to that USB in UEFI mode in BIOS (You'll have to enable UEFI in BIOS first. This does depened on BIOS manufacturer)
12. Skip to step 18 if your disk was already GPT. If not, continue.
13. Type `diskpart`
14. Write `list disk`
15. Write `sel disk n` (n is the number of your NVME disk)
16. Write `convert gpt`The operation should convert the disk to GPT.
17. Write `exit`
18. If your BIOS mode was already UEFI, skip to step 20. If not, continue.
19. Run the following commands:

    `diskpart`
      `list disk`
      `select disk n` (n is the number of your NVME disk)
      `list partition`
      `select partition n` (n is the number of the Windows particion. It's ussually the biggest one)
      `shrink desired=260`
      `create partition efi size=260`
      `format quick fs=fat32`
      `list partition`
      `list volume` (Note the volume where Windows is installed)
      `exit`
      `bcdboot X:\windows` (Replace "X" with the volume letter of the Windows OS partition)
20. Reboot your PC, and boot from your NVMe drive in UEFI mode. It should work now.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed response, I am nervous about using diskpart but with your detailed description I will try this and let you know how I get on. Your help is very much appreciated, I would never have found this solution as I am a novice when it comes to operating systems!

Comment: By the way, the Samsung NVMe driver is not essential for booting up. Windows has NVMe drivers that will take control of the drive and boot it up.

Comment: thanks so much for this. I cloned my disk to a new samsung 970 evo plus and it would not boot. 

I booted into my old disk, looked in disk administrator, put my new drive online as it was offline. It was given the drive letter e: then BCDEDIT.exe e:\windows did the trick!

Comment: I'm writing this on a system with a new Samsung 970 EVO Plus NVMe onto which I restored an image that came from an SSD in MBR format, and it works without converting.  Just had to make sure the NVMe driver was enabled before creating the image.

Answer (score 1):

I can now confirm that the problem I experienced booting my cloned Samsung 970 Evo plus NVMe SSD into Windows is now solved!

I was advised by Macrium to try booting into Windows in safe mode. They thought that loading Windows in safe mode with a minimum drivers, etc may enable Windows to boot far enough to find the new drive and load the NVMe drivers. I tried this and it worked! Once I was in Windows in safe mode I went to Device Manager and sure enough the Windows NVMe driver had been loaded and the drive was present.

I then logged out, shut down and restarted the laptop in standard mode and everything loaded as it should. I have now updated to the Samsung NVMe SSD driver and run some diagnostics and benchmarks. All is running as it should and much faster!

I would like to say a big thank you to all the forum users that took the time and effort to provide a response with help and suggestions to assist me with this problem.

Sometimes the simplest solutions are the ones that you don't think of!

Steve

Comment: I had the same problem, both drives were GPT UEFI to begin with. The source drive SATA and the destination drive NVMe. Windows 10 crashed on boot. Booting into safe mode once just as you did solved the problem.

Comment: I follow this steps, safe mode can boot, but normal boot still fail. (my situation is change nvme ssd  to usb storage case (same disk). but back to nvme normal boot well

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem installing Samsung Evo plus and wanted to share what i did in detail from the helpful advice above. There where steps missing that i had to research before I was successful. This might be an easy list to follow for folks who dont know how to access command prompt.

1. Create a windows installation usb
2. Https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/software-download/windows10
3. Run it and create it to the usb device, 2nd option
4. Once done, shut down
5. Swap old m.2 out and install the new cloned one
6. Turn on again press F5 (Esc for Asus) and change the boot sequence to the usb OS
7. When it shows up ignore everything and press shift & f10 to get command prompt
8. To enable normal safe mode type: **Bcdedit /set {default} safeboot minimal** Now press enter
9. Enable safe mode with internet type: **Bcdedit /set {default} safeboot network** Now press enter
10. When you exit, it will ask you are you sure you want to cancel? yes
11. Turn on computer again and either F5 or Esc again, change boot sequence to the new M.2 installed
12. This will reboot and now recognise new m.2 into safe mode
13. Go to start and type system config
14. Go to boot tab, and untick safe mode, click apply
15. Restart into normal desktop :)

Answer (score 0):

> I checked the device manager for installed drivers and sure enough there was no NVMe driver installed under disk controllers, only SATA driver.

Device Manager doesn't show installed drivers. Device Manager shows **connected devices** – you might have 100 different storage drivers installed on the system, but if the only thing currently connected is a SATA AHCI controller, then that's what you will see.

Fortunately, Windows 10 already has generic NVMe drivers built in (along with AHCI drivers, IDE drivers, and all sorts of SCSI drivers – they don't show up in Device Manager either).

The usual problem, whether you're migrating from IDE to AHCI or from AHCI to NVMe, is that the drivers are not configured to start *on boot* – they must be already present very early during the boot process, before the normal "device detection" system has been started. By default, Windows only boot-starts those drivers which were needed at installation time – the rest are still on the system but only get started "on demand" in a later phase.

The generic Microsoft NVMe driver seems to be called `stornvme`. (For comparison, the generic SATA AHCI driver is `storahci`, though Intel RST has a different name.) You can change its configuration using `sc` from an administrator Command Prompt:

```
sc config stornvme start= boot
sc query stornvme
sc qc stornvme
```

Comment: Thanks Gravity, I will try this solution too along with the detailed solution from milo8505 and let everyone know how I get on. I just hope that I can get it going!

Answer (score 0):

I did the same but from a 256 GB nvme SSD to a 1TB one.
I used the 'create system recovery option' in Windows 7 backup (available in Windows 10/11), wrote it to an internally attached HDD.
Replaced the SSD, booted from a recovery USB stick and restored the system image.
The system gave a 'Unaccessible boot device' after initial boot, and system repair could not fix it, neither the manual bcd options through a dosprompt (windows 11 does not have the boot folder on the system disk, but on a separated hidden partition)
I then booted in safe mode, did a CHKDSK /F and rebooted. It all worked, only the partitions where as small as on the original ssd. Used a 3rd party partition tool to move and enlarge the partitions.
All works great now.

Answer (score 0):

I tried several of the suggestions on this forum as my device would show in windows and bios but would not boot. The issue was my boot was set to legacy for storage and pci devices so changed to UEFI then had to convert the drive to GPT and finally booted my Evo 970, would have long given up without this thread ! Thanks everyone

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).